# Is it possible to charge phone faster?

Tags: charging

I know that going to Airplane mode can be useful
But is there any way to charge phone faster?

Answer (score 3):

Turning it off first. Then there's no possible stuff draining energy while it's charging.

Be sure to charge via AC. Charging via USB is much slower.

There's a small chance that the charger you have doesn't draw power as fast as your phone can take it. A charging brick with a slightly higher mA rating *might* get you some quicker charges, but I think it's unlikely (especially if you're using the charger that came with the phone).

Answer (score 0):

I saw [this](https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/plxdevices/legion-meter-charge-your-smartphone-92-faster) a few weeks ago which, if genuine, looks pretty good. I am still sceptical however but would be nice to see if it is successful.

Answer (score -2):

Use DU battery app. By that my phone charges abit quick.I have noticed it alot of times

Link to the app(android) -

http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dianxinos.dxbs&hl=en